# How to pass username and password at the time of handshaking to authenticate use in websocket?

Tags: java, servlets, websocket, tomcat7

i am devloping a group chat appication and i want to send username and password at the time of handshaking.

Here is my client side javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Chat = {};

    Chat.socket = null;

    Chat.connect = (function(host) {
        if ('WebSocket' in window) {
            Chat.socket = new WebSocket(host);
        } else if ('MozWebSocket' in window) {
            Chat.socket = new MozWebSocket(host);
        } else {
            alert("'Error: WebSocket is not supported by this browser.'")
            Console.log('Error: WebSocket is not supported by this browser.');
            return;
        }

        Chat.socket.onopen = function() {
            Console.log('Info: WebSocket connection opened.');
            document.getElementById('chat').onkeydown = function(event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) {
                    Chat.sendMessage();
                }
            };
        };

        Chat.socket.onclose = function() {
            document.getElementById('chat').onkeydown = null;
            Console.log('Info: WebSocket closed.');
        };

        Chat.socket.onmessage = function(message) {
            Console.log(message.data);
        };

    });

    Chat.initialize = function() {
        if (window.location.protocol == 'http:') {
            Chat.connect('ws://' + window.location.host
                    + '/WebSocketDemo/ChatWebSocketServlet');
        } else {
            Chat.connect('wss://' + window.location.host
                    + '/WebSocketDemo/ChatWebSocketServlet');
        }
    };

    Chat.sendMessage = (function() {
        var message = document.getElementById('chat').value;
        if (message != '') {
            Chat.socket.send(message);
            document.getElementById('chat').value = '';
        }
    });

    var Console = {};

    Console.log = (function(message) {
        var console = document.getElementById('console');
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.style.wordWrap = 'break-word';
        p.innerHTML = message;
        console.appendChild(p);
        while (console.childNodes.length > 25) {
            console.removeChild(console.firstChild);
        }
        console.scrollTop = console.scrollHeight;
    });

    Chat.initialize();
</script>
```

and i have used tomcat 7 as a server.

Here is my server side code:

```
@Deprecated
public class ChatWebSocketServlet extends WebSocketServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final String GUEST_PREFIX = "Guest";

    private final AtomicInteger connectionIds = new AtomicInteger(0);
    private final Set<ChatMessageInbound> connections = new CopyOnWriteArraySet<ChatMessageInbound>();

    @Override
    protected StreamInbound createWebSocketInbound(String subProtocol,
            HttpServletRequest request) {
        return new ChatMessageInbound(connectionIds.incrementAndGet());
    }

    private final class ChatMessageInbound extends MessageInbound {

        private final String nickname;

        private ChatMessageInbound(int id) {
            System.out.println("stage 1");
            this.nickname = GUEST_PREFIX + id;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onOpen(WsOutbound outbound) {
            connections.add(this);
            System.out.println("user:" + this);
            String message = String.format("* %s %s", nickname, "has joined.");
            broadcast(message);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onClose(int status) {
            connections.remove(this);
            String message = String.format("* %s %s", nickname,
                    "has disconnected.");
            broadcast(message);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBinaryMessage(ByteBuffer message) throws IOException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                    "Binary message not supported.");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onTextMessage(CharBuffer message) throws IOException {
            // Never trust the client
            String filteredMessage = String.format("%s: %s", nickname,
                    HTMLFilter.filter(message.toString()));

            broadcast(filteredMessage);
        }

        private void broadcast(String message) {
            for (ChatMessageInbound connection : connections) {
                try {
                    CharBuffer buffer = CharBuffer.wrap(message);
                    connection.getWsOutbound().writeTextMessage(buffer);
                } catch (IOException ignore) {
                    // Ignore
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here i want to send User's credential before actual handshaking to authenticate user.
so how i can to in this?

Comment: Is anyone know how authentication will be done in WebSocket?

Comment: You are supposed to authenticate over https before you begin using Websockets. But how the websocket code validates the user is logged in after that sounds a little weak to me.  You should read http://www.christian-schneider.net/CrossSiteWebSocketHijacking.html and https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/websocket-security